# Mock/Stub constructor

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, jasmine

I have the following code:

```
class Clients
  constructor : ->
    @clients = []

  createClient : (name)->

    client = new Client name
    @clients.push client
```

I am testing it with Jasmine BDD like this:

```
describe 'Test Constructor', ->

  it 'should create a client with the name foo', ->

    clients = new clients
    clients.createClient 'Foo'
    Client.should_have_been_called_with 'Foo'

  it 'should add Foo to clients', ->

    clients = new clients
    clients.createClient 'Foo'

    expect(clients.clients[0]).toEqual SomeStub
```

In my first test I want to check if the constructor is being called with the correct name. In my second I just want to confirm that whatever came out of new Client was added to the array.

I am using Jasmine BDD and it has a way to create spies/mocks/stubs but it seems it's not possible to test constructor. So I am looking into a way to test the constructor it would be nice if there is a way that I don't need an extra library but I am open to anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best plan here is to pull out the creation of the new `Client` object to a separate method. This will allow you to test the `Clients` class in isolation and use mock `Client` objects.

I've whipped up some example code, but I haven't tested it with Jasmine. Hopefully you can get the gist of how it works:

```
class Clients
  constructor: (@clientFactory) ->
    @clients = []

  createClient : (name)->
    @clients.push @clientFactory.create name

clientFactory = (name) -> new Client name

describe 'Test Constructor', ->

  it 'should create a client with the name foo', ->
    mockClientFactory = (name) ->
    clients = new Clients mockClientFactory

    clients.createClient 'Foo'

    mockClientFactory.should_have_been_called_with 'Foo'

  it 'should add Foo to clients', ->
    someStub = {}
    mockClientFactory = (name) -> someStub
    clients = new Clients mockClientFactory

    clients.createClient 'Foo'

    expect(clients.clients[0]).toEqual someStub
```

The basic plan is to now use a separate function (`clientFactory`) to create new `Client` objects. This factory is then mocked in the tests allowing you to control exactly what is returned, and inspect that it has been called correctly.

Comment: I was afraid I would have to solve it this way. Nonetheless great answer thank you.

Answer (score 9):

It **is** possible to stub out constructors in Jasmine, the syntax is just a bit unexpected:

```
spy = spyOn(window, 'Clients');
```

In other words, you don't stub out the `new` method, you stub out the class name itself in the context where it lives, in this case `window`.  You can then chain on a `andReturn()` to return a fake object of your choosing, or a `andCallThrough()` to call the real constructor.

See also: [Spying on a constructor using Jasmine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347631/spying-on-a-constructor-using-jasmine)

Comment: This doesn't really work if Clients is a variable on a closure.

Answer (score 0):

My solution ended up similar to @zpatokal

I ended up using a module accross my app (not really big app), and mocking from there. One catch is that `and.callThrough` won't work, as the constructor is going to be called from the Jasmine method, so I had to do some trickery with `and.callFake`.

On unit.coffee

```
class PS.Unit
```

On units.coffee

```
class PS.Units
  constructor: ->
    new PS.Unit
```

And on the spec files:

```
Unit = PS.Unit

describe 'Units', ->
  it 'should create a Unit', ->
    spyOn(PS, 'Unit').and.callFake -> new Unit arguments... # and.callThrough()
    expect(PS.Unit).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

Answer (score 0):

Clearer solution with recent jasmine version:

```
window.Client = jasmine.createSpy 'Client'
clients.createClient 'Foo'
expect(window.Client).toHaveBeenCalledWith 'Foo'
```