# How to mock dependency classes for unit testing with mocha.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

Given that I have two ES6 classes.

This is class A:

```
import B from 'B';

class A {
    someFunction(){
        var dependency = new B();
        dependency.doSomething();
    }
}
```

And class B:

```
class B{
    doSomething(){
        // does something
    }
}
```

I am unit testing using mocha (with babel for ES6), chai and sinon, which works really great. But how can I provide a mock class for class B when testing class A?

I want to mock the entire class B (or the needed function, doesn't actually matter) so that class A doesn't execute real code but I can provide testing functionality.

This is, what the mocha test looks like for now:

```
var A = require('path/to/A.js');

describe("Class A", () => {

    var InstanceOfA;

    beforeEach(() => {
        InstanceOfA = new A();
    });

    it('should call B', () => {
        InstanceOfA.someFunction();
        // How to test A.someFunction() without relying on B???
    });
});
```

Comment: read about [DI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can use SinonJS to create a [stub](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#stubs) to prevent the real function to be executed.

For example, given class A:

```
import B from './b';

class A {
    someFunction(){
        var dependency = new B();
        return dependency.doSomething();
    }
}

export default A;
```

And class B:

```
class B {
    doSomething(){
        return 'real';
    }
}

export default B;
```

The test could look like: (**sinon < v3.0.0**)

```
describe("Class A", () => {

    var InstanceOfA;

    beforeEach(() => {
        InstanceOfA = new A();
    });

    it('should call B', () => {
        sinon.stub(B.prototype, 'doSomething', () => 'mock');
        let res = InstanceOfA.someFunction();

        sinon.assert.calledOnce(B.prototype.doSomething);
        res.should.equal('mock');
    });
});
```

**EDIT: for sinon versions >= v3.0.0, use this:**

```
describe("Class A", () => {

    var InstanceOfA;

    beforeEach(() => {
        InstanceOfA = new A();
    });

    it('should call B', () => {
        sinon.stub(B.prototype, 'doSomething').callsFake(() => 'mock');
        let res = InstanceOfA.someFunction();

        sinon.assert.calledOnce(B.prototype.doSomething);
        res.should.equal('mock');
    });
});
```

You can then restore the function if necessary using `object.method.restore();`:

> **var stub = sinon.stub(object, "method");**
> Replaces object.method with a
> stub function. The original function can be restored by calling
> `object.method.restore();` (or `stub.restore();`). An exception is thrown
> if the property is not already a function, to help avoid typos when
> stubbing methods.

Comment: Woa. That easy. Didn't think of altering the prototype. Thanks! :) Do you have a tip on how to mock the constructor? Seems not to work the same way?

Comment: Check this answer I gave a few days ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32550115/mocking-javascript-constructor-with-sinon-js/32551410#32551410

Comment: How would you do this for the constructor of B?

Comment: [ts-mock-imports](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-mock-imports) Is a library I created that allows you to mock out a class import without running the class constructor.

Comment: This seems to be deprecated https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/issues/1761 The right aproach is on this docs https://sinonjs.org/releases/v5.0.3/stubs/

Comment: That link is now bad.  Use this: https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/stubs/