# How to use sinon (or something else) to check that es6 ts class was created with parameters

Tags: node.js, typescript, sinon

Let's say I am using `auth0` in typescript in Node.js

I have this class I want to test:

`ClassToTest.ts`

```
import { AuthenticationClient, AuthenticationClientOptions } from 'auth0';

export class ClassToTest {
    public static getClient(): AuthenticationClient {
        let options = {
            domain: global.myConfig.DOMAIN,
            clientId: global.myConfig.CLIENT,
            clientSecret: global.myConfig.SECRET
        } as AuthenticationClientOptions;
        let auth0 = new AuthenticationClient(options);

        return auth0;
    }
}

export default ClassToTest;
```

Now I want to write a unit test that confirms that the right values were passed into `options`.

I am trying sth like

```
import { expect } from "chai";
import * as sinon from 'sinon';

import ClassToTest from "./ClassToTest";
import { AuthenticationClient, AuthenticationClientOptions } from "auth0";

describe("ClassToTest", () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
       global.myConfig.DOMAIN = 'someValue';
    });
    
    afterEach(() => {
        sinon.restore();
    });

    it("uses right options", async function () {
        let usedOptions: AuthenticationClientOptions;
        sinon.stub(AuthenticationClient.prototype, 'constructor')
            .callsFake((opts: AuthenticationClientOptions) => {
                usedOptions = opts;
            });
        expect(usedOptions.domain).to.equal('someValue');
    });
})
```

This gives me:

> error TS2345: Argument of type '"constructor"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'keyof AuthenticationClient'.

Comment: Do you want to get `options` in the test case and assert it?

Comment: @LinDu correct, that is exactly what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't stub the `constructor` of a JS class like that, see [issues/1892](https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/issues/1892).

A solution is to use [proxyquire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/proxyquire) to stub out the `auth0` module and its `AuthenticationClient` class. Besides, we can use `.getCall(n).args` to get the arguments of stub for the nth call.

E.g.

`classToTest.ts`:

```
import { AuthenticationClient } from './auth0';

export class ClassToTest {
  public static getClient(): AuthenticationClient {
    let options = {
      domain: global.myConfig.DOMAIN,
      clientId: global.myConfig.CLIENT,
      clientSecret: global.myConfig.SECRET,
    };
    let auth0 = new AuthenticationClient(options);

    return auth0;
  }
}

export default ClassToTest;
```

`auth0.ts`:

```
// Simulate auth0 module
export class AuthenticationClient {
  constructor(options) {}
}
```

`classToTest.test.ts`:

```
import proxyquire from 'proxyquire';
import sinon from 'sinon';

describe('76519308', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    global.myConfig = global.myConfig || {};
    global.myConfig.DOMAIN = 'someValue';
  });

  it('should pass', () => {
    const AuthenticationClientStub = sinon.stub();
    const ClassToTest = proxyquire('./classToTest', {
      './auth0': {
        AuthenticationClient: AuthenticationClientStub,
      },
    }).default;
    ClassToTest.getClient();
    sinon.assert.match(AuthenticationClientStub.getCall(0).args[0].domain, 'someValue');
  });
});
```