# Is this the correct way to spy on a function in Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I have been trying to spy on the original function, but I think I am not doing it right.

Based on [the accepted answer of this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347631/spying-on-a-constructor-using-jasmine?rq=1) I wrote this spec:

**testSpec.js**

```
describe("Test:", function() {
    var user = "foo";
    var pass = "bar";

    it("Expects login() will be called", function(){
      var loginSpy = spyOn(window, 'login').andCallThrough();
      login(user, pass);
      expect(loginSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();      
    });    
});
```

Now my test passes of course. But when I remove the line `login(user, pass)` the test fails. I have chained the spy with `andCallThrough()`. Now in my `test.js` I am calling `login(user, pass)` on `document.ready` so it is being called I guess. But I am still confused as to how can I get to spy on the `login()` function that actually is being executed from my `test.js` script. I dont think even with `andCallThrough()` it is spying on `login()` present in `test.js`. Anything I am missing out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the use of `document.ready` in your `test.js`. Doing this, the test will run immediately but the call to `login` will be done after `document.ready` so it will be called but after the test was run. You should refactor your code so the function that is  passed to `document.ready` can be called separately.

before:

```
$.ready(function(){
  login('foo', 'bar');
})
```

after:

```
//init.js
function init(){
  login('foo', 'bar');
}

//index.html
<script src="init.js"></script>
<script>
  $.ready(init)
</script>
```

Now you can call the `init` function in your test

```
describe("Test:", function() {
    var user = "foo";
    var pass = "bar";

    it("Expects login() will be called", function(){
      var loginSpy = spyOn(window, 'login').andCallThrough();
      init();
      expect(loginSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();      
    });    
});
```

Comment: Cool! Pretty clean solution! Thanks. +1