# SpyOn private property which is a class with methods

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, spy

My Angular app uses the `oidc-client` UserManager class to manage OAuth authentication.

I have a service as below

```
export class AuthService {
  private userManager: UserManager
  private readonly configService: ConfigService;
  constructor(configService: ConfigService) {
    this.configService = configService;
  }
...
  async load(): Promise<any> {
    config = this.configService.getConfig();
    this.userManager = new UserManager(config);
    const user = await this.userManager.getUser();
...
```

And my spec file setup is as below:

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    const spy = jasmine.createSpyObj('UserManager', ['getUser']);
    spy.getUser.and.returnValue(mockUser);
    const configSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('ConfigService', ['getConfig']);
    configSpy.getConfig.and.returnValue(mockConfig);

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        AuthenticationService,
        { provide: UserManager, useValue: spy },
        { provide: AppConfigService, useValue: configSpy }
      ]
    });
    authService = TestBed.inject(AuthenticationService);
    appConfigSpy = TestBed.inject(ConfigService) as jasmine.SpyObj<ConfigService>;
    userManagerSpy = TestBed.inject(UserManager) as jasmine.SpyObj<UserManager>;
  });
```

...and my first test case is :

```
    it('should initialise the user manager', async () => {
      // arrange 
      userManagerSpy.getUser.and.resolveTo(mockUser);
      appConfigSpy.getConfig.and.returnValue(mockConfig);

      // act
      await authService.load();

      // assert
      expect(userManagerSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

I'm getting a 404 error when running tests and I'm guessing the `new UserManager(config)` and/or the `this.userManager.getUser()` is trying to make an httpRequest when I want it to return the mock values.

How do I spyOn `userManager` and mock the return value from `getUser()`?

My understanding was that the TestBed.configureTestModule providers is for setting up the services which are DI'd into the service, not members of the service itself.

Comment: How are you injecting `UserManager` ? You can just mock that class

Comment: I must confess it's not my code and UserManager is not being injected, I've updated my code to for clarity

Comment: Still, we do not know how are you injecting this value, this is not a [minimal-reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Apologies, I've added more context to my question. The only thing that's being injected is the service which retrieves configuration

Answer (score 0):

You need to spy on a constructor. In JS world you can do something like this

```
spyOn(window, 'UserManager').andReturn(...);
```

Topic about spying on constructor: [Spying on a constructor using Jasmine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347631/spying-on-a-constructor-using-jasmine)

Instead of ... You can create a spy/mock and later check if #getUser() function was called. Or you can simply create Moco implementation for #getUser().

However remember that "Everytime a mock returns a mock a fairy dies". In other words - this is not the best way to write test and it indicates problem with code quality. If the UserManager was created inside function - it's not the service and I think it should not have logic.

Maybe you can refactor the code in a way that the config is used to call method of a service injected in constructor of AuthService?